# Define new constants in wp-config

Tags: wp-config

I have extended my Wordpress with a page that connects to an external Api. I want to define constants for the `url`, `key` and `secret`. Do you think the `wp-config.php` is a good place to define these constants or better to define the constants in a separate file?

Comment: yes it's looks like a good place for me. another good place in my point of view is in a plugin file if you need to install this plugin on a few places.

Comment: [Must Use Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)